# Python package metadata endpoint not available in JFrog Artifactory PyPI repository

Tags: python, pip, artifactory, pypi

I'm using JFrog Artifactory as an artifact store to keep private python modules. When our build server pushes a compiled python module to the Artifactory PyPI repository it makes a GET request to another endpoint (to validate that the module was pushed). I can see that the module was stored but the /json endpoint returns a 404 not found. When I try doing this on the public PyPI site I get a metadata document in JSON format.

Is this a feature of PyPI which isn't supported by JFrog? Or is it a problem with my build artifacts? I already tried searching around but couldn't find much information about this.

https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyPIJSON?action=show&redirect=PyPiJson

URL which works on PyPI: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/{{ packagename }}/json

Example: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests/json

URL which gives 404 on Artifactory: https://{{ myorg }}.jfrog.io/{{ myorg }}/api/pypi/{{ myteam }}/{{ packagename }}/json

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Artifactory only supports the PyPi [simple API](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyPISimple).
The JSON API is not supported at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is this scheduled for development at some point?

Comment: I created a Jira issue with the requirement, you can watch it to track progress - https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-16101